# Can I suppress vacuous 'More...' links on Doxygen class reference pages?

Tags: doxygen

A Doxygen class reference page consists primarily of lists of class members, each followed by its brief description (if such exists).  The member proper is a link to a details page for that member.  Invariably the brief description is followed by a 'More...' link.  The content of this link is identical to that of the member proper.  This 'More...' link suggests - at least to me - that a more extended description is available at the other end of that link.  This is misleading when the member has only a brief description.  In that case the link points to a page which simply repeats that brief description and then states "Definition at line NN of file abcxyz.ext."

Is there anyway to get Doxygen to suppress these frustratingly vacuous 'More...' links?

Answer (score 2):

*(Tentative answer as this particular case is not something I've ever needed to do.)*

In the case that you want to remove *all* detailed descriptions (and thus, presumably, the links to it) you might be able to modify the 'layout' file to make that section invisible.

Reference: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html#layout

Alternatively..

From your description it sounds like `REPEAT_BRIEF` is set on.  If there really is no description beyond the first full stop then you *may* find that turning REPEAT_BRIEF off will remove the link, as the text there will truly be vacuous.

Answer (score 2):

Experimental patch for doxygen 1.8.10, which allows you to remove the "More..." links by using "USE_MORE_LINK = NO" in Doxyfile.

```
<!-- language: diff -->
=== modified file 'src/classdef.cpp'
--- src/classdef.cpp    2015-07-06 11:29:12 +0000
+++ src/classdef.cpp    2015-07-06 11:37:57 +0000
@@ -1802,12 +1802,14 @@

   // HTML only
   ol.pushGeneratorState();
-  ol.disableAllBut(OutputGenerator::Html);
-  ol.docify(" ");
-  ol.startTextLink(getOutputFileBase(),
-      anchor.isEmpty() ? QCString("details") : anchor);
-  ol.parseText(theTranslator->trMore());
-  ol.endTextLink();
+  if (Config_getBool("USE_MORE_LINK")) {
+    ol.disableAllBut(OutputGenerator::Html);
+    ol.docify(" ");
+    ol.startTextLink(getOutputFileBase(),
+        anchor.isEmpty() ? QCString("details") : anchor);
+    ol.parseText(theTranslator->trMore());
+    ol.endTextLink();
+  }
   ol.popGeneratorState();

   if (!anchor.isEmpty())

=== modified file 'src/config.xml'
--- src/config.xml  2015-07-06 11:29:12 +0000
+++ src/config.xml  2015-07-06 11:57:09 +0000
@@ -366,6 +366,13 @@
 ]]>
       </docs>
     </option>
+    <option type='bool' id='USE_MORE_LINK' defval='1'>
+      <docs>
+<![CDATA[
+ Experimental parameter, which allows you to remove the "More..." links by using USE_MORE_LINK = NO.
+]]>
+      </docs>
+    </option>
     <option type='list' id='ABBREVIATE_BRIEF' format='string'>
       <docs>
 <![CDATA[

=== modified file 'src/filedef.cpp'
--- src/filedef.cpp 2015-07-06 11:29:12 +0000
+++ src/filedef.cpp 2015-07-06 11:31:41 +0000
@@ -373,8 +373,8 @@
       ol.writeString(" \n");
       ol.enable(OutputGenerator::RTF);

-      if (Config_getBool("REPEAT_BRIEF") ||
-          !documentation().isEmpty()
+      if ( (Config_getBool("REPEAT_BRIEF") || !documentation().isEmpty() ) &&
+          Config_getBool("USE_MORE_LINK")
          )
       {
         ol.disableAllBut(OutputGenerator::Html);

=== modified file 'src/memberdef.cpp'
--- src/memberdef.cpp   2015-07-06 11:29:12 +0000
+++ src/memberdef.cpp   2015-07-06 11:37:48 +0000
@@ -1805,22 +1805,24 @@
       {
         static bool separateMemberPages = Config_getBool("SEPARATE_MEMBER_PAGES");
         ol.pushGeneratorState();
-        ol.disableAllBut(OutputGenerator::Html);
-        //ol.endEmphasis();
-        ol.docify(" ");
-        if (separateMemberPages ||
-            (m_impl->group!=0 && gd==0) ||
-            (m_impl->nspace!=0 && nd==0)
-           ) // forward link to the page or group or namespace
-        {
-          ol.startTextLink(getOutputFileBase(),anchor());
-        }
-        else // local link
-        {
-          ol.startTextLink(0,anchor());
-        }
-        ol.parseText(theTranslator->trMore());
-        ol.endTextLink();
+        if (Config_getBool("USE_MORE_LINK")) {
+          ol.disableAllBut(OutputGenerator::Html);
+          //ol.endEmphasis();
+          ol.docify(" ");
+          if (separateMemberPages ||
+              (m_impl->group!=0 && gd==0) ||
+              (m_impl->nspace!=0 && nd==0)
+             ) // forward link to the page or group or namespace
+          {
+            ol.startTextLink(getOutputFileBase(),anchor());
+          }
+          else // local link
+          {
+            ol.startTextLink(0,anchor());
+          }
+          ol.parseText(theTranslator->trMore());
+          ol.endTextLink();
+        }
         //ol.startEmphasis();
         ol.popGeneratorState();
       }
```

Comment: Well that is decidedly _NOT_ the semantics I had hoped for.  I strive to write  a brief definition for every symbol.  Sometimes I provide additional material.  It is written as an elaboration of the brief description.  Hence I specify

  REPEAT_BRIEF = YES

What I want is for doxygen to determine whether a symbol has any documentation beyond a brief description.  When there is none I want 'More...' suppressed as it suggests falsely that there actually is more to read.  By contrast when there is an elaboration I want 'More...' to lead to a paragraph that starts with the brief description.

Comment: I can try to implement the idea of setting up:

USE_MORE_LINK = NO

http://doxygen.10944.n7.nabble.com/Get-rid-of-quot-More-quot-td6612.html

Comment: Per the title of my original question I want to suppress **_vacuous_** More... links.  I want the More... link when there is additional documentation beyond just a brief description.  I want it suppressed when it is **_vacuous_**, when there is no documentation at all or there is **_only_** a brief description. I do not think that this requires a new Doxyfile tag.  I would argue that this is behavior that all users would appreciate.  At the very least, if there is a new tag then the above behavior should be the default and the tag should allow one to recover today's unfortunate behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this is annoying.  To solve this, here are two options:

(1.) Set REPEAT_BRIEF=NO in the Doxygen configuration file.  The More link and the Detailed Description section will not be generated if there is no details comment. However, this has the side effect that the brief description will not be repeated in the Detailed Description.  In your source code comments, you will need to copy the brief description into the details comment if you want it to be repeated.  For my project, this is not a good solution.

(2.) Alter the Doxygen.exe so that it does what you want it to do.  Download the source code, edit, and build.  The behavior that I want is this: if there is no details comment, do not generate a Detailed Description section (and of course do not create a More... link); if there is a details comment and REPEAT_BRIEF=YES, create a Detailed Description section which includes the brief description.  To do this, edit namespacedef.cpp by changing

```
bool NamespaceDefImpl::hasDetailedDescription() const
{
    bool repeatBrief = Config_getBool(REPEAT_BRIEF);
    return ((!briefDescription().isEmpty() && repeatBrief) ||
          !documentation().isEmpty());
}
```

to

```
bool NamespaceDefImpl::hasDetailedDescription() const
{
    //bool repeatBrief = Config_getBool(REPEAT_BRIEF);
    return (//(!briefDescription().isEmpty() && repeatBrief) ||
          !documentation().isEmpty());
}
```

and in classdef.cpp change

```
bool ClassDefImpl::hasDetailedDescription() const
{
  bool repeatBrief = Config_getBool(REPEAT_BRIEF);
  bool sourceBrowser = Config_getBool(SOURCE_BROWSER);
  return ((!briefDescription().isEmpty() && repeatBrief) ||
          !documentation().isEmpty() ||
          (sourceBrowser && getStartBodyLine()!=-1 && getBodyDef()));
}
```

to

```
bool ClassDefImpl::hasDetailedDescription() const
{
  bool repeatBrief = Config_getBool(REPEAT_BRIEF);
  bool sourceBrowser = Config_getBool(SOURCE_BROWSER);
  return (//(!briefDescription().isEmpty() && repeatBrief) ||
          !documentation().isEmpty() ||
          (sourceBrowser && getStartBodyLine()!=-1 && getBodyDef()));
}
```

You may want to change the implementation hasDetailedDescription() in other classes. For instructions on how to build doxygen, see https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/install.html  I am using Doxygen 1.10.

Comment: Did you also take e.g call graphs (ettc.) into consideration in case there is no detailed description?

Comment: Based on the logic of the code, I don't see a reason why call graphs would not work as expected with these changes. However, my project does not use call graphs so I did not test that.

Comment: Call graphs / referenced by etc. only appear when there is detailed documentation.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** This issue with documenting a file has been fixed in **Doxygen** with https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/10615. Thanks to [albert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23159733/can-i-suppress-vacuous-more-links-on-doxygen-class-reference-pages/77909654?noredirect=1#comment137389437_77909654).

As shown by the other answers there is no simple solution. I use Doxygen 1.9.4 and as verified by [Albert in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23159733/can-i-suppress-vacuous-more-links-on-doxygen-class-reference-pages/77909654#comment137369344_77909654) this also persists in version 1.10.0. Here is an example where I get the vacuous 'More...'. Just document a file with:

```
/*!
 * \file
 * \brief This is a short description.
 */
```

Then in the parsed documentation you will find:

```
This is a short description. More...
```

but behind that `More...` is no more information. I help me with a simple addition. I just append  `No details` to the `\brief` description so I get a hint in Doxygen for this example with:

```
This is a short description. No details. More...
```

If you click `More...` you can verify that there is no more ;-)

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: @albert I updated the answer. But I don't think that the version matter. Just adding a two letter word to the \brief comment should be doable with every Doxygen version.

Comment: The current doxygen version is 1.10.0, so this might help as well. I cannot say anything more about it as a code example about where the "More ...`" appears.

Comment: @albert I have improved my answer with an example. It would be very nice if you could check with version 1.10.0 if this issue persists and report it here, maybe with an answer?

Comment: I saw the change in the answer and I just checked with the doxygen 1.10.0 version, unfortunately, it is still present (even when setting `REPEAT_BRIEF = NO`). Best is to create an issue for it in the doxygen issue tracker on GitHub (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues)

Comment: @albert Thank you :-) I will have a look at Github doxygen for an existing issue about this. I can't believe that this wasn't mentioned even after 10 years.

Comment: I can very well imagine it, people are quite "lazy" and don't write an issue, fortunately there are some people that are more persistent and write an issue.

Comment: I think I already saw what the problem is for the `\file` command ...

Comment: I've just pushed a proposed patch to github (pull request 10615, https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/10615).

Comment: Code has been integrated in master on GitHub

Answer (score -1):

It might be a bit late but I faced the same problem and solved it easily, with the following doxyfile configuration:

```
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC = NO
BRIEF_MEMBER_DESC = YES
REPEAT_BRIEF = NO
EXTRACT_ALL = NO
# Since EXTRACT_ALL is NO, configure the following as you wish. In my case
EXTRACT_PRIVATE = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS = YES
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: still getting "More..." link with this configuration